# Capture exception during request deserialization in WebAPI C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I'm using WebAPI v2.2 and I am getting WebAPI to deserialise JSON onto an object using [FromBody] attribute.  The target class of the deserialisation has a [OnDeserialized] attribute on an internal method, like this:

```
[OnDeserialized]
internal void OnDeserialisedMethod(StreamingContext context) {
    // my method code
}
```

I know for a fact there is a problem with the code inside this method, I've stepped through it and found it.  The problem for me is that I get no exception at all.  What happens is this method gets jumped out of and the exception seems to be ignored.  My controller action gets called and my target object is not properly populated because this serialisation method has not been correctly executed.

My question is; how can I capture an exception that occurs during deserialisation in WebAPI?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

Comment: I've done as suggested on that web page but it still doesn't pick up the exception?  Deriving from ExceptionHandler class and registering with `config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new Exceptions.MyExceptionHandler());`

Comment: They do actually catch the exception, but not the exception I want.  It catches the exception where my target class is not properly populated, it is still not seeing any exception from the OnDeserialized method.  I need to catch errors BEFORE it enters the controller action method and this seems to be an issue here, they appear to just be ignored.

Comment: oh sorry it is my bad. it is for response serialization not for request deserialization.

Comment: No problems, I have updated the title to state request deserialization as I think that will make it more clear.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know if by any chance you found the solution to this issue?

Comment: Nope sorry!  I read an MS article somewhere that said that they are completely ignored before a certain point in the request lifecycle (I'd link it here if I could remember it).  A solution that did occur to me but I haven't actually implemented personally is that you could capture and save them in a static class (not sure how you'd link them to the current request unless you could grab that as well at the time of the exception) and use an ActionFilter to check for the existence of any exceptions before executing the action...possibility there I'm sure.

Comment: I suppose if you were able to capture the request at the time of the exception you could always save the exception within the request itself and check it in the ActionFilter that way, without using a static class at all, that way it would be garbage collected after the request had finished as well, which is always good.

Comment: Hi. Not completely sure if this can help you, but if you are using [FromBody] attribute and you want to get exceptions during deserialization, it is possible trough ModelState. ModelState can tell you which errors (exceptions) occured during deserialization. Do you want me to elaborate more on this in proper answer, or am I completely off with my suggestion? :-)

Comment: That looks interesting, but I've never come across it before so I can't say for certain.  I will take a look when I get a min and see - thanks though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've written up a filter (as suggested in various comments) that checks the ModelState and throws an exception if serialization errors did occur. Beware though, that this may not contain only serialization exceptions - that could be adjusted by specifing the concrete exception type in the `Select` statement.

```
public class ValidModelsOnlyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
        else
        {
            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (var state in actionContext.ModelState)
            {
                if (state.Value.Errors.Count != 0)
                {
                    exceptions.AddRange(state.Value.Errors.Select(error => error.Exception));
                }
            }

            if (exceptions.Count > 0)
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest binding this filter on a global scope. I really can't fathom why it should be ok to ignore deserialization exceptions.

Comment: Automatic upvote for proposing a global solution, rather than an inline check on a single method.

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem and bookmarked your question in hope that someone would provide a solution. I thought using ModelState implied rewriting some validations in the JSON model, but it just works, in fact it's simple and very well done. I didn't have to modify the model, just the controllers.

My code from one of my controllers, StdResponse being the class used to provide the response with details if needed (in this case, for instance) :

```
[HttpPost]
public StdResponse Test([FromBody]StdRequest request)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Work on the data from the request...
    }
    else
    {
        //Retrieve the exceptions raised during deserialization
        var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(v => v.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.Exception));

        List<String> messages = new List<string>();

        foreach (Exception e in errors)
        {
            messages.Add(e.GetType().ToString() + ": " + e.Message);
        }

        return new StdResponse(exchangeVersion, "null", ExecutionResponse.WithError("StdRequest invalid", messages));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check *ModelState.IsValid* inside your controller.
If "OnDeserialisedMethod" throws an exception (or any other model validation fails) it will be *false*, if everything succeed it will be true.