# WebAPI POST [FromBody] Not Binding and Not Throwing Up Error

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to understand why my JSON Object when casted to an specficied object is giving me NULL when one of the attributes sent im my json, which is a number, is larger than Int32. My whole object is not binding and not not throwing up any error, just becoming null.

Now my situation. I started a new project just to understand it, and I all the question over here I could found.

I do have this model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestJson.Models
{
    public class Credential
    {
        public int IdSource { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have this Controller:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using TestJson.Models;

namespace TestJson.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("PreAuth")]
    public class PreAuthController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("PostObject")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostObject([FromBody]Credential input)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(Ok(input));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("PostJObject")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostJObject([FromBody]JObject input)
        {
            Credential Credential = input.ToObject<Credential>();

            return await Task.FromResult(Ok(Credential));
        }
    }
}
```

And I have this JSON object:

```
{
    "IdSource": 11111111111111,
    "TransactionDate": "2017-11-24T11:59:01.7567643-02:00"
}
```

So, when I calling `api/PreAuth/PostObject` within the above JSON, I just get null as parameter casted to my object.

But if I call the same JSON `/api/PreAuth/PostJObject`, I can receive the given error below:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.OverflowException",
    "StackTrace": "   em System.Convert.ToInt32(Int64 value)..."
}
```

So, If I change my JSON object modifying my `IdSource` attribute to a shorter number, both of my methods works fine because it can fit to int limits.

My point is; Why when I call the method `PostObject` expecting a specified object in parameter and it couldn't cast my JSON into it properly it is giving me null and not filling my others properties?

The best scenario would be at least see some error, but I just get nothing at all. All my object is swallowed and it becomes like an stealth error and the caller don't know exactly which attribute he is giving wrong.

How can I workaround this using object as parameter instead JObject?

Comment: @Sparrow I already know the cause of the error, but Im wondering why Im not seeing it and the convertion is just swallowing my object and don't give me nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure your JsonFormatter on your HttpConfiguration (application Startup).

An example:

```
protected virtual void ConfigureFormatter(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () =>
            {
                JsonSerializerSettings result = new JsonSerializerSettings();

                //Include the type name to be able to deserialize into the derived instead of the base type.
                result.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;

                //Do not include null properties in serialized JSON.
                result.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

                return result;
            };

            JsonMediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = JsonConvert.DefaultSettings();
            config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Add(jsonFormatter);

            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
        }
```

**EDIT**

The previous answer works for extended objects (I thought your were having null values on that).

You can however add a custom filter for filtering valid models like explained here:

[Capture exception during request deserialization in WebAPI C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835869/capture-exception-during-request-deserialization-in-webapi-c-sharp)

Comment: How is that supposed to work and allow me to see the error when the JSON is being casted into my object? Because I'm still seeing my object as null.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you had and inheritance which was giving you the null problem. So instead of getting an exception on your scenario, you just got the whole parameter null, right? Having a custom filter for filtering valid models could be an option? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835869/capture-exception-during-request-deserialization-in-webapi-c-sharp

Comment: I could use this. It is very close to the answer I would like to have. So you can edit your answer, so i can upvote it. Thank you.