# How to catch and handle invalid json exception with Newtonsoft json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have the model:

```
 public class PushManyRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("ids")]
        public List<string> Ids { get; set; } 
    }
```

and for my controller I have the following signature:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PushMany([FromBody] PushManyRequest request)
        {
         ...
        }
```

As you can see I'm trying to map a request to the model. And it's convenient and understandable!
I can add `[Required(ErrorMessage=<message>)]` attribute and I will have my own error for a client if there is no `ids`

But what to do if a client pass me invalid JSON? For example:

```
{
    "ids": [
    "123",
    "234"
    "235     <---------------------- invalid!!!
    ]

}
```

I will answer for a client something like:

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "description": [
    "Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: \". Path 'ids[991]', line 999, position 1.",
    "Unexpected end when deserializing array. Path 'ids[991]', line 999, position 1.",
    "Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path 'ids[991]', line 999, position 1."
  ]
}
```

As you can see it's pretty unfriendly. It's my inner parsing error and client don't need to know about it. I would like to return something like:

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "description": "Sorry, but your JSON is invalid. Please, check it and try again"
}
```

But I don't understand where I can write it and how to catch this situation. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the documentation about error handling? https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture exception during request deserialization in WebAPI C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835869/capture-exception-during-request-deserialization-in-webapi-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into modelstates.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  IEnumerable<ModelError> allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
  foreach (ModelError item in allErrors)
  {
        orderErrors += item.ErrorMessage;
        break;
  }
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {

      var context = (HttpContextBase)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
      context.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
      string requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

      log.write_to_log(requestBody, "null", "ModelState is not valid - " + orderErrors); //Saves to your log 

       return new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode)400);
   }
}
if (orderErrors != "")
{
      return new HttpResponseMessage((HttpStatusCode)400);
}
else 
{
     //Something happens
}
```

Something like this should work ^^